# Which input's shape for timeseries_dataset_from_array?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, tensorflow2.0

I have a dataset with `n` columns, of which the firsts `n-1` are features, and the `n`th is the label.

After read [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/timeseries_dataset_from_array) documentation, I have subdivided the aforementioned dataset in `x_train` and `y_train` by:

```
x_train = data.iloc[:, :n-1]
y_train = data.iloc[:, n]
```

Then:

```
dataset_train = keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
x_train,
y_train,
sequence_length=7,
batch_size=batch_size,
shuffle=False
)
```

but, in this way, I don't get the right output shape.

I would like to know:

1. Is it necessary to shift `y_train` with an offset equal to `sequence_length`?
2. Which is the right data format for `timeseries_dataset_from_array()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is necessary to shift. You can see it in the code below, using the variable `seq_length` for indexing.

The input can be of any shape, as long as `data` and `targets` share the same first dimension.

The data format can be univariate:

```
import tensorflow as tf

seq_length = 3

x = tf.range(25)[:-seq_length]

y = tf.range(25)[seq_length:]

ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(x, y,
                                                          sequence_length=seq_length,
                                                          batch_size=1)

for present_values, next_value in ds.take(5):
    print(tf.squeeze(present_values).numpy(), '-->', next_value.numpy())
```

```
[0 1 2] --> [3]
[1 2 3] --> [4]
[2 3 4] --> [5]
[3 4 5] --> [6]
[4 5 6] --> [7]
```

Or multivariate:

```
import tensorflow as tf

seq_length = 3

x = tf.concat([
    tf.reshape(tf.range(25, dtype=tf.float32)[:-seq_length], (-1, 1)),
    tf.reshape(tf.linspace(0., .24, 25)      [:-seq_length], (-1, 1))], axis=-1)

y = tf.concat([
    tf.reshape(tf.range(25, dtype=tf.float32)[seq_length:], (-1, 1)),
    tf.reshape(tf.linspace(0., .24, 25)      [seq_length:], (-1, 1))], axis=-1)

ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(x, y,
                                                          sequence_length=seq_length,
                                                          batch_size=1)

for present_values, next_value in ds.take(5):
    print(tf.squeeze(present_values).numpy(), '-->', tf.squeeze(next_value).numpy())
```

```
[[0.   0.  ]
 [1.   0.01]
 [2.   0.02]] --> [3.   0.03]
[[1.   0.01]
 [2.   0.02]
 [3.   0.03]] --> [4.   0.04]
[[2.   0.02]
 [3.   0.03]
 [4.   0.04]] --> [5.   0.05]
[[3.   0.03]
 [4.   0.04]
 [5.   0.05]] --> [6.   0.06]
[[4.   0.04]
 [5.   0.05]
 [6.   0.06]] --> [7.   0.07]
```

Comment: In case the number of features n is big. Could be possible to insert x in a for loop? I have tried: `x_reshaped = [tf.reshape(train_data.iloc[:-seq_length, column].values, (-1, 1)) for column in range(len(x_train.columns))]` , but it gets an error with `tf.concat()`.

Comment: I don't understand your question and I'm tempted to say that this would be more appropriate for a new question

Comment: What is the difference with sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit?